# Noise on sound devices after listening to media for a few minutes

Tags: sound, lubuntu, 22.04, 22.10, noise

I installed Lubuntu 22.04 LTS (and tested version 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu) on a live USB), and the following problem occurs: when listening to some media that contains audio, either through local music files (through VLC) or through a browser (through Firefox) (ex.: YouTube), after a few seconds or a few minutes the sound is interrupted and there is a loud noise (proportional to the volume at the time of the error) and continuous from the sound devices, which is not silenced when muting the sound, and only stops after a few seconds after closing the program that runs that media.

In previous versions of Lubuntu this did not happen. It only seems to happen when there is audio playing, as videos and music with muted volume do not cause the problem. It also happens after such an event that, when in the browser, it drastically reduces the capability to play media on websites like YouTube, becoming too slow and muted. Despite this, navigability is not affected.

In case the volume is muted after the event, the sound does not come back, it is necessary to restart the pc to get back to normal, as just exiting the session is not enough. I can't say about system conditions, I thought maybe the RAM or processing consumption would increase over time, but apparently everything is normal at this point.

In the dmesg output I found some lines like this, maybe it's important:

```
x86/PAT: pulseaudio:1139 map pfn RAM range req uncached-minus for [mem 0x04d00000-0x04d95fff], got write-combining
```

Here is some system information:

```
Chassis: laptop
Operating System: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-43-generic
Architecture: x86-64
Hardware Vendor: Positivo Informatica SA
Hardware Model: Q232A
```

After reading about the topic in some places, I saw that after the error the sound is restored with the command `pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload`. Just typing `pulseaudio -k` or `sudo alsa force-reload` also gives satisfactory results. It doesn't solve the problem, as it keeps happening, but it helps in some way.

How to go about solving this problem? As I don't have much knowledge about the operating system, I don't even know where to start providing the relevant information, so I ask for help about the commands to be used.

Thank you in advance for your considerations.

**Note: I'm still using Lubuntu 22.04 LTS.**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu Mate 22.04. I solved it by using a different kernel.

Comment: This problem persists for Lubuntu 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu), how to proceed to have this problem fixed in newer versions of the system, without having to install an older kernel? I'm afraid this problem won't be fixed "spontaneously" in updates over time.